# Eliminar etiquetas html y dejar sólo el contenido de texto

Tags: c#, html, regex

Tengo este texto:

```
<span id="valor">texto</span><span id="valor1" class="texto">Fecha
```

La idea es que quede:

```
textoFecha
```

Tener en cuenta que no siempre va a ser `span` y no siempre van a ser las mismas cadenas, la idea es tomar todas las etiquetas (entre `<` y `>`) y eliminarlo.

Comment: Podrías investigar como hacer expresiones regulares en google y crear la propia, si no hay código inicial tuyo no es fácil ayudarte, se supone que el foro esta para resolver problemas concretos y tu situación esta basada en muchas posibles respuestas, deberías limitar tu pregunta a algo mas concreto.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: No es para cerrar, y el autor no responde a los comentarios, así que sólo resta responder bajo protesta: @Braiam por favor, intenta poner un poco más de esfuerzo al hacer una pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

No uses expresiones regulares para procesar HTML, especialmente si el texto fue ingresado por el usuario. Hay herramientas especialmente diseñadas para eso, que utilizan el [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Usando la librería [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/), sólo hay que referirse al [**InnerText**](http://html-agility-pack.net/inner-text) del documento:

```cs
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

```cs
string html = @"<span id=""valor"">texto</span><span id=""valor1"" class=""texto"">Fecha";
```

```cs
HtmlDocument dom = new HtmlDocument();
dom.LoadHtml(html);
string resultado = dom.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yNCmgr

Answer (score -1):

Ya tengo la solución  `@"<.*?>"`

Comment: Esto fallaría con `<input type='text' value='x > 3 * y'>`